# Move SharePoint Search databases to new Search Application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search, database

I wonder whether it is possible to attach search databases to a new Search Application in same farm/different farm ? I found all Microsoft articles only mentioned attach Search Application to "renamed" databases, which can understand that they are already databases of that application before

Comment: which database you want to move and whats the reason for doing that?

Comment: We're doing farm migration so we want to move all of existing search databases to new farm. I think there's some settings in site Search Application which would take time if we do from scratch

Comment: do you have too many customization at your search service application?

Comment: We have a long list of custom property name mapped to crawled properties in Search Schema

Comment: But first I wonder if migration of search database is a common practice or normally we would just configure from scratch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to migrate farm from one environment to another environment, I suggest you could back up the search service application and restore it in another environment.

We can back up and restore search service application by PowerShell command or Central Administration.

And the two procedures can back up all of the search components including the databases, the search service configuration, and all of the index files.

More references:

Back up Search service applications in SharePoint 2013.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748635.aspx

Restore Search service applications in SharePoint 2013

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748654.aspx

Comment: Does this work in case that new environment has a different domain ?

Comment: Yes, it can restore the search service application in another environment.https://www.petri.com/backup-restore-service-applications-sharepoint-2013  https://jerryyasir.wordpress.com/2014/11/02/restore-search-service-application/